# PhantomJs rendering

Tags: phantomjs

Is there any limit to the number of characters for the file name to get it render from phantomJs?

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://github.com/', function() {
      window.setTimeout(function(){
      var filename = encodeURI('The code shown here is also available in various examples included with PhantomJS. You are also recommended to explore the use of PhantomJS for page automation, network monitoring, screen capture, and headless testing The code shown here is also available in various examples included with PhantomJS. You are also recommended to explore the use of PhantomJS for page automation, network monitoring, screen capture, and headless testing');
      console.log('filename: ' + filename);
      page.render(filename + ".png");
      phantom.exit();}, 100);
});
```

This  file is not getting render through phantomJs.

Can someone please help here?

Comment: Why not find out about the limit yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has anything to do with PhantomJS, but basically with your OS. There is a size limit for the file path name in every OS.

According to the [naming convention in Windos OS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath) -

> In the Windows API (with some exceptions discussed in the following
>   paragraphs), the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is
>   defined as 260 characters. A local path is structured in the following
>   order: drive letter, colon, backslash, name components separated by
>   backslashes, and a terminating null character. For example, the
>   maximum path on drive D is "D:\some 256-character path string"
>   where "" represents the invisible terminating null character for
>   the current system codepage. (The characters < > are used here for
>   visual clarity and cannot be part of a valid path string.)